# ERROR: syntax error at or near "e2ecalc" LINE 25: when 'E2E' then e2ecalc(quoteID);Please check

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

```
if ( connMode is not null and serviceType is not null ) then
     
    if ( position('LL'  in serviceType) > 0 ) then
      PERFORM llcal(quoteID);
    else
      case connMode
      when 'E2E' then e2ecalc(quoteID);
      when 'P2E' then p2ecalc(quoteID);
      when 'P2P' then p2pcalc(quoteID);
      end case;
    end if;
  else
```

Comment: if ( position('LL'  in serviceType) > 0 ) then
      PERFORM llcal(quoteID);
    else
      case connMode
      when 'E2E' then e2ecalc(quoteID)
      when 'P2E' then p2ecalc(quoteID)
      when 'P2P' then p2pcalc(quoteID)
      end case;
    end if;
  else

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "e2ecalc"
LINE 26:       when 'E2E' then e2ecalc(quoteID)  ---getting same error.

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "e2ecalc" LINE 26: when 'E2E' then e2ecalc(quoteID).Kindly  suggest to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

You use procedural `CASE` statement. This command contains PLpgSQL statements (not expressions like SQL `CASE`). You should to use `PERFORM` statement there.

```
case connMode
  when 'E2E' then PERFORM e2ecalc(quoteID);
  when 'P2E' then PERFORM p2ecalc(quoteID);
  when 'P2P' then PERFORM p2pcalc(quoteID);
end case;
```

Comment: A lot of thanks Sir . A lot of thanks Sir. It works.